# Not able to call instance_double twice

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I'm writing a test fot rspec to check that items are added into a class that I use like an array

```
    describe '#collection' do
        let(:process) {
            instance_double("WebServerProcess", :cpu => 33, :mem => 22, :pid => 1, :port => 8000)
        }
        it 'return the collection' do
            WebServersCollection.add process
            expect(subject.collection).to eq([process])
        end
        it 'should add with <<' do
            WebServersCollection << process
            expect(subject.collection).to eq([process])
        end
    end
```

Show me this error

> Failure/Error: expect(subject.collection).to eq([process])
>          # was originally created in one example but has leaked into another example and can no
>   longer be used. rspec-mocks' doubles are designed to only last for one
>   example, and you need to create a new one in each example you wish to
>   use it for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error tells you everything you need to know.

You can't do that and

> you need to create a new one in each example you wish to use it for